# Craft CMS Utilities misses email option

Tags: craftcms

I'm new to craft and I have to make a school project.

At the moment I'm stuck when it comes down to sending emails.

When a visitor lands on a page it can choose to subscribe to a fictional newsletter. In my twig template I use this as a form with an input field and a submit button.

But in some way I'm not satisfied with the craft documentation because it's not really helpful. I have no clue where I have to trigger an email being send or whatsoever. In the documentation they are talking about some system messages but when I look for that option, I can't find it anywhere (Maybe because I dont't pay for it?)

Here is an image what I mean:

[image]

If someone knows a way how to send emails without plugins, please let me know.

At the moment, my GMAIL smtp is setup correctly

Comment: Did you read: [Craft CMS / Email](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/mail.html)  ?  (BTW: your pictures are worthless/unreadable)

Comment: I did.. that's why I said that I'm not satisfied with the documentation. 
Like, they are talking about a feature I don't have?